# Qual a diferença entre pg_query e pg_execute?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Sou novo com Postgre e vejo `pg_query` e `pg_execute` na aplicação que estou trabalhando, no entando não consigo ver diferença entre as duas. Tenho que fazer uma inserção e não tenho certeza de qual usar.

Qual a diferença entre as duas e qual a melhor ou mais ágil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A diferença entre ambos é que o [`pg_execute`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-execute.php) suporta [*prepared statements*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepared-statements.php) e o [`pg_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-query.php) não suporta.

É interessante trabalhar com *prepared statements* pois isso protege sua aplicação contra ameaças de segurança como um [*SQL Injection*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

Comment: Existe alguma diferença de performace entre eles ?

Comment: Acredito que o `pg_query` tem um desempenho minimamente melhor, o que não justifica seu uso, pois esse ganho mínimo será perdido no tratamento da variável antes de enviar o insert.

Comment: Foi uma pergunta de curiosidade muito obrigado